# Bounding $|x_i-\lambda|\leq \epsilon \lambda$ when $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq \lambda^2 n + \epsilon$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq \lambda n$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Fix $0\leq \epsilon \leq 1$. Given $\lambda \geq 1, x_i\geq 0$, I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq \lambda n$. I also know that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq \lambda^2 n + \epsilon$. I am trying to prove a multiplicative error on each $x_i$, mainly something along the lines of

$$|x_i - \lambda| \leq f(\epsilon) \lambda$$

Where $f(\epsilon)$ is some function of $\epsilon$, say $f(\epsilon)=2\epsilon$. Is there any inequality that would bound that distance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I literally thought of two minutes after typing the question. Let $x_i = \lambda + \delta_i$ for some $\delta_i$. Then we have that

$$\sum_i (x_i^2) = \sum_i (\lambda + \delta_i)^2 = \lambda^2 n + 2\lambda \sum_i \delta_i + \sum_{i}\delta_i^2 < \lambda^2 n+\epsilon$$
But we have that

$$\sum_ix_i = \sum_i \lambda+\delta_i = \lambda n + \sum_i \delta_i > \lambda n$$

Which implies

$$\sum_i\delta_i > 0$$

Combining with first inequality

$$\lambda^2 n +0 + \sum_i \delta_i^2 < \lambda^2n + 2\lambda \sum_i \delta_i 
 + \sum_i \delta_i^2 < \lambda^2 n + \epsilon$$

Or simply

$$\sum_i \delta_i^2 < \epsilon$$

Or

$$|\delta_i| \leq \sqrt{\epsilon} \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}\lambda$$